# How to convert yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z into yyyy-mm-dd hh mm ss?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This may be trivial but somehow I was not able to solve it. I am trying to convert a column 'timestamp' with this format '2017-07-06T20:42:17Z' **which is an OBJECT** into format Datetime yyyy-mm-dd hh mm ss.

I tried this code with pandas but it does not work:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%TZ')
```

Can someone guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pass the right `format`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' )
```

Comment: It worked but when I check the change in df.dtypes, it still shows OBJECT for this column. Why would that be?

Comment: @cocoo84hh object contain the datetime types

Comment: ah, so it should be fine then? I will find out once I will apply date-time operations. hopefully, it will work.

Comment: @cocoo84hh yes .

Comment: You should do: 
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str.lstrip('Z').astype('datetime64[s]').
Then it says dtype= datetim64[ns].

Answer (score 0):

You should use:
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str.lstrip('Z').astype('datetime64[s]')